# Export , image as PNG PDF and PPT in Highchart

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using react-jsx-highcharts , library and want to export highchart as PNG , PDF and PPT , with some additional information attached to them . my exisiting code uses domToImage , to download the chart and i need the imageURL to to pass it to my existing fucntion to make it work , but not able to do it .
1 Tried to get chart's instance with ref didn't work
2 Tried to get chart's instace using  const chart = Highcharts.charts[0]; that aslo didn't worked .

```
\`import React ,{useRef} from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import {
HighchartsChart,
Chart,
withHighcharts,
XAxis,
YAxis,
Title,
Legend,
Caption,
Tooltip,
HeatmapSeries,
} from "react-jsx-highcharts";
import addHighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import Heatmap from "highcharts/modules/heatmap.js";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
Heatmap(Highcharts);
addHighchartsMore(Highcharts);

const plotOptions = {
};

const colorAxis = {
minColor: "#FFFFFF",
maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors\[0\],
};

const colorAxis2 = {
stops: \[
\[0, "#ff0000"\],
\[1, "#b3b1b1"\],
\],
min: -1,
max: 1,
};

let dataLabel = false;
let title = \["Heat Map", "Correlation Matrix"\];

const HeatMapChart = ({
YaxisData,
YaxisTitle,
XaxisTitle,
YAxisCategory,
XAxisCategory,
isMatrix,
}) =\> {
const FontSizes = Math.max(Math.floor(-0.75 \* YAxisCategory.length + 13.75),3);
const chartRef = useRef(null);

const handleExport = () =\> {
const chart = Highcharts.charts\[0\];
if (chart) {
const dataUrl = chart.getSVGForExport({
type: "image/png",
sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight,
});
console.log(dataUrl,"ssssssssssssssssss");
// Do something with the image URL, such as displaying or downloading it
}
};

return (
\<div className="app"\>
\<div id="printChartPNG" className="heatmapChart"\>
\<Button onClick={handleExport}\>Export Chart\</Button\>
\<HighchartsChart
plotOptions={plotOptions}
colorAxis={isMatrix ? colorAxis2 : colorAxis}
ref={chartRef}
\\>
\<Chart /\>
\<Title\>{isMatrix ? title\[1\] : title\[0\]}\</Title\>
\<Legend layout="vertical" align="right" verticalAlign="middle" /\>
{/\* added this to make correlation matrix x-axis on top\*/}
\<XAxis
categories={XAxisCategory}
opposite={isMatrix ? true : false}
labels={{
x: -12,
maxWidth: "10px",
style: { fontSize: `${Math.min(FontSizes, 11)}px` },
overflow: "justify",
}}
\\>
{isMatrix ? (XaxisTitle = "") : XaxisTitle}
\<XAxis.Title\>{XaxisTitle}\</XAxis.Title\>
\<Legend /\>
\</XAxis\>
\<YAxis
categories={YAxisCategory}
labels={
isMatrix
? {
step: 1,
style: { fontSize: `${Math.min(FontSizes, 11)}px` },
}
: { step: 0 }
}
\\>
{/\* \<Categories /\> \*/}
{isMatrix ? (YaxisTitle = "") : YaxisTitle}
\<YAxis.Title\>{YaxisTitle}\</YAxis.Title\>
\<Legend
              align="right"
              layout="vertical"
              margin="0"
              verticalAlign="top"
              y="2"
              symbolHeight="2"
            /\>
{isMatrix ? (dataLabel = true) : (dataLabel = false)}
\<HeatmapSeries
name="Data1"
data={YaxisData}
dataLabels={{
enabled: dataLabel,
color: "#000000",
style: {
//calculate font size based on number of vairables selected in the chart . took 3 points to calculate the equation one being 3px for 30 variables 10px for 10 variables .
fontSize: `${Math.min(FontSizes, 10)}px`,
fontWeight: 200,
padding: 0,
},
align: "center",
}}
/\>
\<Tooltip headerFormat="\<em\>{point.key}{point.xkey}\</em\>\<br/\>" /\>
\</YAxis\>
\<Caption align="center"\>\</Caption\>
\</HighchartsChart\>
\</div\>
\</div\>
);};
```

export default withHighcharts(HeatMapChart, Highcharts);`

Tried using passing ref to the chart and calling export funtion .
expecting imageURL that can be further passed to existing download functionality ,

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Yadav, First of all, I recommend you to use the officially supported wrapper for Highcharts in React: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official in which chart exporting is really easy to achieve. However, I've found a discussion in this thread: https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts/issues/374 which can be very helpful in your case.